# Segmentation Fault in C while writing instertion code

Tags: c, visual-studio, data-structures, insertion

I have just started with DSA and was making a program to insert an element. The program worked fine sometimes(2 out of 10 times ) rest of the times it gave me segmentation fault or nothing showed up.

Please help me out as I am not able to rectify the problem.

I have pasted the code below:

```
#include<stdio.h>

void insert(int arr[],int size,int index,int ele,int capacity) 
{
for( int i=size-1;i>=index;i++){

arr[i+1]=arr[i];

}
arr[index]=ele;
}


void display(int arr[],int size){
for(int i=0;i<size;i++){
    printf("\n The element at index %d is %d",i,arr[i]);
    
}

}

int main(){

int arr[100];
int size;
int ele;
int index;
printf("\n Enter how many elements do you want to have in an array ::");
scanf("%d",&size);
printf("\n Enter the elements::");
for(int i=0;i<size;i++){
    printf("\n \n Enter Element :: %d",(i+1));
    scanf("%d",&arr[i]);
}
display(arr,size);
printf("\n \n At which index you want to insert the element ?");
scanf("%d",&index);
printf("\n \nEnter which element you want to insert");
scanf("%d",&ele);
insert(arr,size,index,ele,100);
size = size + 1;
fflush(stdin);
display(arr,size);

}
```

[image]

Comment: Fix the indention, the code isn't readable.

Comment: `int i=size-1` ... `arr[i+1]` bug here.

Comment: This seems like a very good time to learn how to use a *debugger* to catch the crash and locate when and where in your code it happens, and also examine values of variables at the point of the crash.

Comment: `for( int i=size-1;i>=index;i++)` Shouldn't `i++` be `i--`?

Comment: Thanks a lot..it worked..since I am starting from the last index it has to be i--